# I want add some conditions and validation to a colums in XLSX file after download in asp.net mvc Ex: age should be above 18 for age column

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Download function asp.net
I want add some conditions and validation to a colums in XLSX file after download in asp.net mvc Ex: Issued year must be greater than 2019

public ActionResult DownloadExcel(string statename, string deptname, string certname)
{

```
        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
        // Create an instance of the ExcelPackage class
        ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();

        // Get a reference to the worksheet
        var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");



        // Add headers to the worksheet
        worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "State";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Department";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "certificate";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Issued Year";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Certificate_id";




        worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 3, 1].Style.Locked = true;

        var data = new List<test>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            data.Add(new test
            {
                Name = statename ,
                Email = deptname ,
                Phone = certname 
            });

        }
        
        int row = 2;
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = item.Name;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = item.Email;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value = item.Phone;
            row++;
        }

        // Save the workbook to a MemoryStream
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(memoryStream);

        // Set the position of the MemoryStream to the beginning
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        // Return the Excel file as a FileResult
        return File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "mydata.xlsx");
    }
```